# Chrome and Firefox CSS border issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, border

Hi I have this issue with my border being shown in Firefox and Chrome. It looks FINE in Safari.

Fiddle/live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hirokotenshi/JhfS8/

The one in Chrome and Firefox looks jagged somehow.
Here: 
http://i923.photobucket.com/albums/ad77/Chapter-s/Screenshot2013-03-26at43905PM_zps5d62d1c9.png

My CSS:

```
#whatsnew {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-right: 50px solid #d52b1e;
  padding: 35px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Anyone knows how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a link to a live demo or a maybe make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Martyn0627 hey i do not have a live demo but I have screenshots of it stated in my post!

Comment: @Martyn0627 oh i created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hirokotenshi/JhfS8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually by design - borders are joined diagonally at the corners, so what you're seeing is the edges of the right border tapering to meet the other 1px edges.

The best solution I can think of is using a wrapper div, applying the 1px border to that, and then keeping the red border in the inner div:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="whatsnew">
  <div id="whatsnewtitle">What's new?</div>
  <div id="whatsnewcon">
  <b>Do you know?</b><br />
  <br />
  Royal Dutch Shell plc filed its Annual Report on Form 20-F for the year ended December 31, 2012 with the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission.
  <br />
  <br />
  <div style="text-align: right;">
  <a href=""><b>Find out more...</b></a>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
margin-top: 50px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Verdana;
}
#whatsnew {
border-right: 50px solid #d52b1e;
padding: 35px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JhfS8/1/

(Quick and dirty hack...)

If you wanted to avoid the grey border to the right of the wrapper, you can change that to red too:

```
    border-right-color: #d52b1e;
```

... and if you wanted to be **really** clever, you could use `position: relative` and negative margins to 'pull' the inner div back out over the border, so the grey disappears behind the red:

http://jsfiddle.net/JhfS8/2/

Comment: GREAT!! IT WORKS!! Thanks so much!!This forum is awesome thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Try: `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` or `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` or add some padding in addition to the `backface-visibility` one

Comment: Still doesn't help :( Anyone can help me please? It's quite a major project.. Need it to look neat!!